# What StatusCode should I return to parameters out of range

Tags: http-status-codes

I am not sure what status code should I return to client. When the request has parameters out of range. My API support paging from page 1 to (let's say) 50. Which status code should server return to

`page < 1 || page > 50`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http codes and explanation for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

You should use some of the 4xx codes, because it's error on client side.

Let's use the **400 (Bad Request)** status code. It's general error code, so it should be right.